# RewriteRules for .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, regex

> **This question has an *accepted* answer at
>   [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56172960/11436089)**

---

I have a PHP file named as `otp.php`.

When URL in the URL bar is

```
http://localhost/college/otp/MTA=/teacher
```

It should be treated as

```
http://localhost/college/otp.php?user=MTA=&role=teacher
```

For this, I created `.htaccess` file in *http://localhost/college/*:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost  [NC]
RewriteRule    (.*otp)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+=)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)  $1.php?user=$2&role=$3  [NC,L]
```

But, `otp.php` file says:

> Notice: Undefined index: role in C:\wamp\www\college\otp.php on line
>   11
>
> Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\wamp\www\college\otp.php on line
>   11

[image: **See Image**]

---

*Created question here after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933302/how-to-write-rewriterules-for-htaccess#comment98870766_56094417) Comment.*

**Two Different Results:**

[image]

Comment: This question seems to have been closed too brashly - it's not a "duplicate" of the catch-all "mod_rewrite" question. There is no immediate problem with the mod_rewrite directive itself. The problem shown here looks like it is caused by a conflict with mod_negotiation/MultiViews (which is not covered at all by the linked question).

Comment: With the information provided in the question, I don't think any particular conclusions can be drawn as to the cause.  One of the topics covered in the linked duplicate is debugging mod_rewrite rules, which is the best advice that can be offered, given the question's current state.

Comment: I am unable to find the answer there...